# Problems with plotly_IMAGE

Tags: save, plotly

I am saving several graphs that I have created with:

```
plotly_IMAGE(graph, format = "png", out_file = filename)
```

but:

Error in process.image(append_class(resp, "image")) : 
  Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).

I have provided user name and API KEY, so I don't know where my problem is. Furthermore, this code worked but suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: If you get the error from the remote server then I guess there's not much you can do. Perhaps you should reach out to their support?

Comment: This code was working and suddenly it stop working. :( I need to save plots Thanks. I would like to know if someone has had the same problem and how it was fixed. I don't know is generalized problem.

Thanks